# Is there a good GLSL hash function?

Tags: math, glsl, gpu, numerics

So I am still getting upvotes for my ancient comment on this question: [What's the origin of this GLSL rand() one-liner?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12964279/whats-the-origin-of-this-glsl-rand-one-liner)

And it got me thinking, what would a good GLSL hash function look like? There are obvious use cases for it like Perlin noise. There are some properties that I would look for in a good implementation.

- Stable under different precisions (mediump,highp). This could be configurable.
- Should be usable in ES2, so it can not use integer support
- ALU only, no textures
- Not looking for cryptographic qualities, but for large periods and "perceptual" randomness
- Should ideally produce the same results on a bare minimum spec ES2 implementation

Practically I think most people just mix x,y inputs by multiplying them with some prime numbers, adding them, multiplying them again, and looking the result coordinate up in a tiling texture of random numbers with nearest sampling.

So this question is less about looking for "the answer" but curiosity if there is a good way to do this. I would also like to know arguments about why it is not possible.

Answer (score 1):

"Murmur" style of hash functions seem to perform very well for this kind of application, check out https://nullprogram.com/blog/2018/07/31/ and https://www.shadertoy.com/view/WttXWX. Quoting from the later:

```
//bias: 0.17353355999581582 ( very probably the best of its kind )
uint lowbias32(uint x)
{
    x ^= x >> 16;
    x *= 0x7feb352dU;
    x ^= x >> 15;
    x *= 0x846ca68bU;
    x ^= x >> 16;
    return x;
}


// bias: 0.020888578919738908 = minimal theoretic limit
uint triple32(uint x)
{
    x ^= x >> 17;
    x *= 0xed5ad4bbU;
    x ^= x >> 11;
    x *= 0xac4c1b51U;
    x ^= x >> 15;
    x *= 0x31848babU;
    x ^= x >> 14;
    return x;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This question is the top result on Google, so I'd like to direct any hapless passersby to a blog post by Nathan Reed based on [this paper](https://jcgt.org/published/0009/03/02/), which concluded that the best trade-off in terms of performance and quality for visual noise is a very simple hash called **PCG Hash**:

```
uint pcg_hash(uint input)
{
    uint state = input * 747796405u + 2891336453u;
    uint word = ((state >> ((state >> 28u) + 4u)) ^ state) * 277803737u;
    return (word >> 22u) ^ word;
}
```

Source:
https://www.reedbeta.com/blog/hash-functions-for-gpu-rendering/